# My create.cshtml view page not opening ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-5, asp.net-core-6.0

I am creating an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application, the application runs successfully but whenever I want to add an actor (based on project) the create view page does not work. It's showing an internal server error.

This is the error I get:

> AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Actors_Create.ExecuteAsync() in Create.cshtml

```
@model Actor

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add New Actor";
}

<div class="row text">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
        <p>
            <h1>Add New Actor</h1>
```

The error is being highlighted on the ViewData line.

My create.cshtml

```
 @model Actor
    
 @{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Add New Actor";
 }
    
 <div class="row text">
     <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
         <p>
             <h1>Add New Actor</h1>
         </p>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
                 <form class="row" asp-action="Create">
                     <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    
                     <div class="mb-3">
                         <label asp-for="ProfilePictureURL" class="form-label"></label>
                         <input asp-for="ProfilePictureURL" type="text" class="form-control"/>
                         <span asp-validation-for="ProfilePictureURL" class="text-danger"></span>
                     </div>
    
                     <div class="mb-3">
                         <label asp-for="FullName" class="form-label"></label>
                         <input asp-for="FullName" type="text" class="form-control"/>
                         <span asp-validation-for="FullName" class="text-danger"></span>
                     </div>
    
                     <div class="mb-3">
                         <label asp-for="Bio" class="form-label"></label>
                         <input asp-for="Bio" type="text" class="form-control"/>
                         <span asp-validation-for="Bio" class="text-danger"></span>
                     </div>
    
                     <div class="mb-3">
                         <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-outline-success float-end"/>
                         <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" asp-action="Index"> Show All</a>
    
                     </div>
    
                 </form>
    
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

This is my `ActorsController.cs`:

```
 using eTickets.Data;
 using eTickets.Data.Services;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    
 namespace eTickets.Controllers
 {
     public class ActorsController : Controller
     {
         private readonly IActorsService _service;
    
         public ActorsController(IActorsService service)
         {
             _service = service;
         }
    
         public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
         {
             IEnumerable<Models.Actor>? data = await _service.GetAll();
             return View(data);
         }
         public IActionResult Create()
         {
             return View();
         }
     }
 }
```

I am using .NET 6 and Visual Studio version 17.2.5.

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but try setting the ViewData in your Controller.

Comment: `AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Actors_Create.ExecuteAsync() in Create.cshtml` is not the error but the stack trace. I suggest you share the error message. Besides, you said `The error is being highlighted on the ViewData line.`, do you mean the line for ViewData["Title"]? If so, what if you remove it?

Comment: I added the ViewData to the controller as @Joost00719 suggested. But once I did that that's when this error came **InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.String', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'eTickets.Models.Actor**

Comment: @Rena yes i mean the ViewData line, and I tried removing it but the above error still popped up

Comment: This issue is caused by model does not match. Your frontend required model Actor, but your backend is just passed string to frontend.